# Erlang algorithm to return list of pairs of integers which when added to each other equal X

Tags: erlang

Given a list, for example

```
[1, 45, 1, 99, 3, 5, 95, 1, 5, 97, 3, 99, 87]
```

Return the pairs from that list that add up to 100. As an item is consumed, it should not be re-evaluated. In the case above, the output would be:

```
[{1,99}, {1, 99}, {3,97}, {5,95}]
```

The list is not assumed to be sorted, as in the example repeating pairs should work.

Pros/cons of approaches would be good to understand (BigO complexity, space/time).

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried?

Comment: Are there any limitations as to "overlapping" pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shell, as it uses recursive anonymous function, it works only with R17, but it will be ok in a module with earlier erlang version

```
1> L = [1, 45, 1, 99, 3, 5, 95, 1, 5, 97, 3, 99, 87].
2> F= fun F([],R) -> R;
2>        F([H|T],R) -> Rest = lists:dropwhile(fun(X) -> X+H /= 100 end,T),                 
2>                      case Rest of
2>                          [] -> F(T,R);
2>                          [Found|_] -> F(lists:delete(Found,T),[{H,Found}|R])
2>                      end
2> end.
#Fun<erl_eval.36.90072148>
3> F(L,[]).                                                                                                   
[{5,95},{3,97},{1,99},{1,99}]
4>
```

It reproduces exactly what I would do if I have to do it myself:

- take the first element of the list,
- look for a pair in the rest of the list,

  - if no pair restart the process with the rest of the list,
  - if one pair found, record that pair, remove the element found from the rest of the list and restart with the remaining list.
- continue until the list is emty.

This first implementation was in the *make it work* spirit, I have done a faster one, sorting the list first. The following module implements the 2 solutions plus some functions to test and evaluate the performances (the new solution is much faster for long list in the 2 extreme cases: no solution or every term belong to a pair). On my PC, s2 is more than 2500 time faster than s1 with a random list of 100000 elements.

```
-module (sum).

-compile([export_all]).

s1(L,S) -> s1(L,S,[]).

s1([],_S,R) -> R;
s1([H|T],S,R) -> 
    Rest = lists:dropwhile(fun(X) -> X+H /= S end,T),                 
    case Rest of
        [] -> s1(T,S,R);
        [Found|_] -> s1(lists:delete(Found,T),S,[{H,Found}|R])
    end.

s2(L,S) ->
    Linc = lists:sort(L),
    Ldec = lists:reverse(Linc),
    s2(Linc,Ldec,S,[]).

s2(Linc,Ldec,_S,R) when Linc == [] ; Ldec == [] ; hd(Linc) > hd(Ldec) -> R;
s2([H,H|Linc],[H,H|Ldec],S,R) when S == 2*H -> s2(Linc,Ldec,S,[{H,H}|R]);
s2([H1|Linc],[H2|Ldec],S,R) when S == H1+H2, H1/=H2 -> s2(Linc,Ldec,S,[{H1,H2}|R]);
s2([H|Linc],Ldec,S,R) when H + hd(Ldec) < S -> s2(Linc,Ldec,S,R);
s2(Linc,[_H|Ldec],S,R) -> s2(Linc,Ldec,S,R).


%% Test and performance

compare(S1,S2) ->
    S = normalize(S1),
    S = normalize(S2).


normalize(S) -> lists:sort([{min(X,Y),max(X,Y)} || {X,Y} <- S]).

shuffle(P) when is_list(P) ->
    Max = length(P)*10000,
    {_,R}= lists:unzip(lists:keysort(1,[{random:uniform(Max),X} || X <- P])),
    R.

test1(S) -> % every term is part of a solution pair
    random:seed(erlang:now()),
    L = shuffle(lists:seq(1,S)),
    test(L,S+1).

test2(S) -> % no solution
    random:seed(erlang:now()),
    L = shuffle(lists:seq(1,S)),
    test(L,2*S).

test3(S) -> % random
    random:seed(erlang:now()),
    L = [random:uniform(2*S) || _ <- lists:seq(1,S)],
    test(L,S).

test(L,S) -> 
    {T1,S1} = timer:tc(sum,s1,[L,S]),
    {T2,S2} = timer:tc(sum,s2,[L,S]),
    compare(S1,S2),
    {T1,T2,S1}.
```

Comment: This is essentially the approach I landed on. I'm thinking there's not much to do to improve it without sorting the input first.

Comment: I added a much faster solution using sort, in my opinion it is more complex to read, and I was not able to write it right at the first time. I don't know which one I would prefer in an interview?

Answer (score 4):

You could use list comprehension with guard to do it.

```
find_pairs(List) ->
  [{X, Y} || X <- List,
             Y <- List,
             X+Y =:= 100].
```

This approach have of course `n^2` complexity, but so does almost any other.  In the end you have to take every element (that's `n`) and verified it with each other (and that's `* n`). You could introduce some optimizations just like the ones suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26817264/1135337) but still big O would stay `n^2`.  So in my opinion there's no point.

If such complexity would cause me some problems and in fact I would have to optimize, I would try to reduce this second `*n`.  Since this second part is just value look-up (for eny given `X` you are looking for `100 -X` in rest of values). you could try to do your looking in gb_tree.  Creating such tree takes some `n log n`, but this is done only once.  And all look-ups would take you `log n`. So in the end such approach would have `n log n` complexity.

In other languages rather than using gb_tree one would just sort list, and do binary searches for value lookup (again bit O being `n log n`).  But one must remember that in Erlang lists are not arrays.  They are "linked lists" and looking up one value in list is not constant, but can have `n` complexity.  And this `n` have impact on our algorithm, that could give us `n * n long n` which is worse than initial `n^2`.

---

**EDIT** after [@Steve Vionski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409228/steve-vinoski) comment about my algorithm not passing some requirements. Using my approach, when pairing values from `[1, 99, 99]`, rather than `[{1, 99}]` I return `[{1,99},{1,99},{99,1},{99,1}]`.

I really need to read more carefully questions.  Thank you Steve for pointing this out.  Still I would like to leave my initial answer as it is, since it clearly shows algorithm complexity, and this is something I concentrated on in my answer.

That said I would like to apologize for any possible confusion, and provide working solution:

```
find_pairs(List) ->
  find_pairs(List, _Pairs = [], _Sum = 100).

find_pairs([], Pairs, _Sum) ->
  Pairs;
find_pairs([First | Tail], Pairs, Sum) -> 
  case pop(Tail, Sum - First) of
    {Second, Rest} ->
      find_pairs(Rest, 
                 [{First, Second} | Pairs],
                 Sum);
    not_found ->
      find_pairs(Tail,
                 Pairs,
                 Sum)
  end.


pop(List, Value) ->
  pop(List, Value, []).

pop([], _Value, _Processed) ->
  not_found;
pop([Value |  Tail], Value, Processed) ->
  {Value, Processed ++ Tail};
pop([Different | Tail], Value, Processed) ->
  pop(Tail, Value, [Different|Processed]).
```

And again about this algorithms complexity.  `find_pairs` just goes trough list, and so does `pop`, so it would seems that it `n^2`.  It turns out that it is not so simple.  There is additional function `++` which, again due to linked-list nature could have `n` complexity.  So in the end, depending on the input, we could experience `n*(2*n)`.  Still in BigO it is `n^2`, but it is worth noticing that putting more work (or lines of code) in algorithm does not guarantee improved performance.

And there is also also simple fix for that.  `++` has complexity of it's left element. So concatenating two lists inside `pop`, rather than adding `Processed` to `Tail`, one could add `Tail` to `Processed`.  That way, when we find our `Value` on `k` position (and after `k` calls) we have to do only `n - k` additional work during concatenation.  This guarantee that `pop` will do more than `n` work.  And we go back to straight `n^2` for whole algorithm, (and not being do dependent on data order).

Comment: Unfortunately this approach fails the requirement "As an item is consumed, it should not be re-evaluated."

Comment: @SteveVinoski Of course you are wright.  I should read questions with little more care :/

Answer (score 0):

I am not that fluent in algorithms and their performance but here is what i have figured out. My general idea is to split list into two sublists with elements >= 50 and < 50. At least this ensures that you do not have to look for the pairs in each of the lists but only between them:

```
-module(test).
-export([add_to_100/1]).

add_to_100([]) -> [];
add_to_100(List) ->
    {L1, L2} = split(List, [], []),
    find_match(L1, L2).

%% Do matching between 2 lists
find_match([], _) -> [];
find_match(_, []) -> [];
find_match([H1|T1], L2) ->
    case match_element(H1, L2, []) of
        {{A, B}, Left} -> [{A, B} | find_match(T1, Left)];
        {{}, Left} -> find_match(T1, Left)
    end.

%% Match every element with list of integers.
%% Return match pair and exclude matched element from list of integers.
match_element(_, [], Rest) -> {{}, Rest};
match_element(E, [H|T], Rest) when E + H == 100 -> {{E,H}, Rest ++ T};
match_element(E, [H|T], Rest) -> match_element(E, T, [H|Rest]).

%% Split input list into two sublists - L1 < 50 and L2 >= 50
split([], L1, L2) -> {L1, L2};
split([H|T], L1, L2) when H < 50 -> split(T, [H|L1], L2);
split([H|T], L1, L2) -> split(T, L1, [H|L2]).
```

Example:

```
85> c(test).
{ok,test}
86> test:add_to_100([1, 45, 1, 99, 3, 5, 95, 1, 5, 97, 3, 99, 87]).
[{3,97},{5,95},{1,99},{1,99}]
87> test:add_to_100([1, 45, 1, 99, 3, 5, 95, 1, 5, 97, -50, 3, 99, 87, 100, 0, 150]).
[{0,100},{3,97},{-50,150},{5,95},{1,99},{1,99}]
```

After implementing it i have realised that it is not handling pairs {50, 50} - anyway you could add it as a special case to this algorithm. Even though this solution is not complete should give you insights into pattern matching, tail recursion and list manipulation in Erlang which you will definitely need while solving this problem.